# CSS Grid auto adjust width on each rows

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I've some little boxes to place, and I have some row of boxes which have like : 3 boxes then 2 boxes on the second row etc...

What I have made so far, was based on flexbox (not really easy to "play" with), so I tried with grid, and have a little problem. What I've made in flexbox (it's what I want on desktop, but of course, when resizing it don't fit properly). Here is what it do with flexbox :

[image]

But then, when I resize the browser :

[image]

So, I know that flexbox isn't really made to do grid like that. So I tried another way, using grid. I know how it's work to make a grid with the same content on each rows, but I don't know how to do it without the same content.

Here is a little snippet of what I've imagine :

```css
.boxes_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes_container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/347x252">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/347x252">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/347x252">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/538x240">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/538x240">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with auto-fill to, but It don't work. I'm pretty sure the answer is not that hard, but It's might be a fonction or I don't know, when I searched on Google I saw a function "fit-content()" but don't really know if that would work there. Tried to do something with that, but didn't worked out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just have two divs, both using flexbox, the first div containing the 33% width items, and the second the 50% width items?

Comment: Hello, because on responsive, it won't fit good, I would like the box to fit, like, when the container can have only two boxes inside, I would like to have 2 boxes + 2 boxes. Not 2 boxes + 1 boxes + 1 boxes + 1 boxes. I would like it to auto adjust

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CSS-Grid. The grid-container will have a set number of columns and that can't change *per row* unless you start a new container.

Comment: the only way to make a consistent collapsable grid like you want would be to have 3 boxes row, 3 boxes row, then 2 boxes row. then you can have the 6 all collapse down to 2 per row so you have then 2, 2, 2, 2, then they can collapse down to 1. but having just 3 then 2 boxes wont collapse down evenly, unless you go 3 straight to 1 box per row. [i hope that made sense lol!]

Comment: Hello @Moose, Yeah I understand, I would like to be able to do that, but I'm trying to find a way to do that with 2 rows, I don't even know if that's even possible but I'm trying to find a way to

Comment: @ThéoBenoit : the issue is with only those 2 rows is no matter what you do the rows wont collapse down to an even amount of boxes per line as you have an odd amount of boxes. tell you what, let me knock up a working example of something and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: see my answer, i can post more in an answer than a comment!

Answer (score 1):

Do either of these layout examples come close to what you are trying to achieve? - you will need to resize browser window to see the collapsing layout.

```
1) 3,2 >> 2,1,2 >> 1,1,1,1,1
```

https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/WgOwRV?editors=1100#0

```
2) 3,2 >> 1,1,1,1,1
```

https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/KxqzoV?editors=1100#0

Also here is an example of what i mean by if you could have 6 boxes in a 3,3,2 it would collapse down neater. 
https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/rZwevy?editors=1100#0

Comment: Not really, But thanks for your help anyway, I'll just do flexbox, width 33% / 50% then under 768px I'll adapt myself with media queries ^^

Comment: ... so basically what i just posted lol xD [minus the flexbox]

Comment: Ah maybe yeah, I mean that was not really what I expected, I expected grid to auto adjust width of everything (like masonry) but It didn't worked out :( It sucks ^^

Comment: ... if you add a background color to one of the layout examples boxes [onethird/onehalf] you can see the size fills the space so one half will be 50% of the width of the row for example.] but here is a link to a flexbox tutorial if thats more what you want! - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I know how flexbox works, (more than grid aha ^^) thanks for your help anyway :D